# Drop Down Box keeps scrolling up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I implemented this to my site from an earlier question but for some reason on Firefox and IE the drop-down box scrolls up by itself. I can't figure out why!

Just click News Feed and as the box drops down, it automatically drops up. It's supposed to drop down and if I click on newfeed again or outside, it's supposed to drop up. But it doesn't do that, it just springs back up.

I am using the JavaScript. What is going on here?

```
$('#bottom').click(function() {
    $('#content').slideDown();
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id !='bottom') {
        $('#content').slideUp();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `#bottom` event handler a bit to prevent the bubbling of the `click` event all the way up to the `document`:

```
//it is important to declare the `event` variable as a parameter of this anonymous function so it can be accessed inside the function
$('#bottom').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#content').slideDown();
});
```

What's happening with your code is that the event handler for the `#bottom` element is being triggered, then after that the event handler for clicking on the `document` fires since the `click` event bubbles up the DOM. `event.stopPropagation()` will stop the event from bubbling.

Docs for `event.stopPropagation()`: http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: Okay i went ahead and did it!! It works on my computer side but when uploaded to my server, it still has that error on firefox and such?